# Is there any way to let Jikes RVM run Java applications with GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jikes

From its website, I read confusing statements.

[ref](http://jikesrvm.org/FAQ): "... Swing and AWT coverage is particularly incomplete. ..."

[ref](http://jikesrvm.org/Related+Work): "The Jikes RVM uses the Classpath libraries, and supports features such as AWT and Swing GUI tool kits from it."

Anyway, I found that I couldn't not run any applications with GUI. Is there any solution to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The Jikes RVM requires the [GNU Classpath](http://www.classpath.org/) library in its `-classpath` in order to provide (incomplete) support for AWT and Swing.

Comment: Jikes RVM only run the class files. How does `javac` help here?

Comment: Poor wording on my part; more above.